# How to completely destroy an Angular 2 application?

Tags: angular, reactjs, micro-frontend

Is there a way to completely destroy an Angular 2 app?
The use-case of this is when an Angular app is embedded in a page of a React app or somewhere else, so after going to another page in the main app you have to completely destroy the Angular app.

There is a `platformBrowserDynamic().destroy();` function which fails by logging:

> Uncaught Error: A platform with a different configuration has been created. Please destroy it first.

Comment: Isn't destorying the <iframe>-whatever tag not enough?

Comment: The angular app is not embedded by iframe. The assets are loaded, and there is a container element for angular app. It works great, except destroyment.,

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution you can destroy your app by this way

```
import { platformBrowser } from '@angular/platform-browser';

platformBrowser().destroy();
```

Comment: Do you know which is the difference between `platformBrowser().destroy()` and `platformBrowserDynamic().destroy()`?. Because the first one works only in production build mode and the second works for dev mode only.

Comment: Coud I call it outside from JS?